# Using ido or helm to auto complete email addresses in mu4e

Tags: helm, completion, ido, email, mu4e

Is there a way to auto-complete email addresses in the mu4e compose window using Ido or Helm rather than the standard *Completions* buffer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variable `mu4e~contacts-for-completion` stores a list of contacts that `mu4e` knows about. The contacts are conveniently stored as `"name <email>"` strings, which is the same thing you want to insert.

Here's an example function that uses the variable together with `ido` to select and insert a contact:

```
(defun select-and-insert-contact ()
  (interactive)
  (insert (ido-completing-read "Contact: " mu4e~contacts-for-completion)))
```

Here's a more elaborate version which will use the partial contact before point (if any) as the initial input when completing. (Most of the code is directly from `mu4e~compose-complete-contact`).

```
(defun select-and-insert-contact (&optional start)
  (interactive)
  (let ((mail-abbrev-mode-regexp mu4e~compose-address-fields-regexp)
        (eoh ;; end-of-headers
         (save-excursion
           (goto-char (point-min))
           (search-forward-regexp mail-header-separator nil t))))
    (when (and eoh (> eoh (point)) (mail-abbrev-in-expansion-header-p))
      (let* ((end (point))
             (start
              (or start
                  (save-excursion
                    (re-search-backward "\\(\\`\\|[\n:,]\\)[ \t]*")
                    (goto-char (match-end 0))
                    (point))))
             (contact
              (ido-completing-read "Contact: "
                                   mu4e~contacts-for-completion
                                   nil
                                   nil
                                   (buffer-substring-no-properties start end))))
        (unless (equal contact "")
          (kill-region start end)
          (insert contact))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: I don't use mu4e anymore, so this is not a copy/paste or tested answer.

The function  `mu4e~compose-complete-contact` seems to provide a list of contacts available for completion : 
https://github.com/djcb/mu/blob/master/mu4e/mu4e-compose.el#L236

You could just feed the list to `ido-completing-read`.

```
(ido-completing-read "Complete contact: " (mu4e~compose-complete-contact)))))
```